# Difficulty creating a query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

TaskType:

```
Id, Descricao
17, Depilação Buço
18, Depilação Pernas
19, Depilação Orelhas
20, Depilação Barba
21, Cortar Unhas Pés
22, Cortar Unhas Mãos
28, Esvaziar Saco Urina
29, Hidratação
36, Medicação
37, Deitar Utente
47, Levar Roupa para Lavandaria
48, Arrumar Lixo
73, Encaminhamento de Utente para Deitar (Pós Almoço)
77, Fazer Cama
```

Then I have the table of Users:

```
codigo, nome
2,      Pedro
6,      Paulo Moura
3,      Bruno
4,      ANTONIO
```

Now I have the table where I register the tasks, where I already made the query that returns the tasks performed on the current day:

```
SELECT raddb.Tarefa.codigo, Colaborador, FimTarefa, Ala, nome, raddb.TipoTarefa.Id, Descricao

FROM raddb.Tarefa LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.TipoTarefa ON raddb.TipoTarefa.Id = raddb.Tarefa.tarefa  

LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.quartos ON raddb.quartos.Codigo = raddb.Tarefa.codigo

LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.Utente ON raddb.Utente.quarto = raddb.quartos.Quarto AND raddb.Utente.Cama = raddb.quartos.Cama

WHERE raddb.TipoTarefa.Id IN ('17','18','19','20','21','22','28','29','36','37','47','48','73','77') AND DATE(FimTarefa) = DATE(NOW())
```

Which returns this:

```
codigo, Colaborador, FimTarefa, Ala, nome, Id, Descricao
150001, 28, 2019-07-31 11:30:08, ALA A, Pedro, 28, Esvaziar Saco Urina
110001, 33, 2019-07-31 12:10:27, ALA A, Pedro, 36, Medicação
110001, 33, 2019-07-31 13:16:27, ALA A, Pedro, 21, Cortar Unhas Pés
```

In this last `query` returns only three tasks performed to Peter this day, the task 28,36 and 21. 
So what I want is that instead of returning the tasks performed today, I would return the tasks that were not performed today, which in this case were the tasks 17,18,19,20,22,29,37 , 47.48,73,77.

Comment: i have trouble and i doubt iam not the one one to understand the logics  off the query vs the example data as there as tables seams to be missing besides the query uses spain/portuguese as table names? Where the example table name is in english.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use left join table column in where condition this work as ainner join  ... move these condition in ON clause for the related  left joined  table

```
  SELECT raddb.Tarefa.codigo
    , Colaborador
    , FimTarefa
    , Ala
    , nome
    , raddb.TipoTarefa.Id
    , Descricao
  FROM raddb.Tarefa 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.TipoTarefa ON raddb.TipoTarefa.Id = raddb.Tarefa.tarefa  
      AND raddb.TipoTarefa.Id IN ('17','18','19','20','21','22','28','29','36','37','47','48','73','77')
  LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.quartos ON raddb.quartos.Codigo = raddb.Tarefa.codigo
  LEFT OUTER JOIN raddb.Utente ON raddb.Utente.quarto = raddb.quartos.Quarto 
        AND raddb.Utente.Cama = raddb.quartos.Cama
  WHERE  DATE(FimTarefa) = DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: This returns the same values, returns the data of the tasks performed. I want you to return the unfulfilled tasks